# How to stream Logging Events from different Python processes to the same terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, logging, microservices

I'm doing integration testing on my services. It is a very chatty network and I'm having a hard time keeping track of the order that different requests are being made in. I would like a way to stream logging messages in the same terminal from different python processes (each their own app/service started in a separate terminal, not mulitprocessing within a single app). They are running on the same machine, so I don't think I should need third party services like the elk stack for this, I just want to redirect my logs on the same machine to the same terminal so that I can see all logs in chronological order.

Environment:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Python3.8
Virtualenv

Logging is performed with the Python logging module to stdout and I am able to customize the handlers.

Not sure what's best here, to try achieve this at the application level or the OS level. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multiple logger for multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718895/python-multiple-logger-for-multiple-modules)

Comment: It does not answer my question. The question there is about multiple modules in the same process launched in the same terminal.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes