# Logging from multiple modules and APIs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

My main program PGM_A calls API2 and another module Subpgm_1. Subpgm_1 invokes SubAPI_1.

```
PGM_A

  -- Subpgm_1

     -- SubAPI_1

  -- API2
```

I would need to write a log file in the following format:
{"@timestamp":"09/10/2022 11:42:33 AM","log.level":"INFO","message":"Main : Refresh started!!! "}

I have the following code in my main program PGM_A:

```
   filename = datetime.now().strftime('Logfile_%H%M%d%m%Y.log')
    logging.basicConfig(filename=filename,
    format='{"@timestamp":"%(asctime)s","log.level":"%(levelname)-1s","message":"%(message)s"}',
    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
    logger = logging.getLogger('Delta_Refresh_Pipeline')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

I am able to get the logs from main program.
But I would need the log messages from APIs and submodule to be written to same log file Logfile.

In short, my log data should look like:

```
{"@timestamp":"09/10/2022 11:42:33 AM","log.level":"INFO","message":"Log from PGM_A "}
{"@timestamp":"09/10/2022 11:42:34 AM","log.level":"INFO","message":"Log from Subpgm_1"}
{"@timestamp":"09/10/2022 11:42:35 AM","log.level":"INFO","message":"Log from SubAPI_1"}
{"@timestamp":"09/10/2022 11:42:36 AM","log.level":"INFO","message":"Log from API2"}
{"@timestamp":"09/10/2022 11:42:37 AM","log.level":"INFO","message":"Log from PGM_A "}
```

Any pointers what modification I have to do in the API code and Subpgm_1? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just do `logger = logging.getLogger()` to log everything with a 'root' logger.

Otherwise, you can use multiple loggers and duplicate the code. So to get Subpgm_1 and SubAPI_1 you should be able to do `logger = logging.getLogger('Subpgm_1')` if they follow the naming convention.

The logs for SubAPI_1 should be under `Subpgm_1.SubAPI_1`. So by logging Subpgm_1 you get it, along with everything "under" it, it follows a nice hierarchy

You can also list all available logger names by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249304/how-to-list-all-existing-loggers-using-python-logging-module) question, in case they don't follow the naming convention. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718895/python-multiple-logger-for-multiple-modules) question for handling multiple loggers

Comment: I tried. No luck. I added "logger = logging.getLogger('Delta_Refresh_Pipeline') " in my API2 a,d subprograms. No logs generated.

Comment: Did you fetch a list of all the available loggers? Is `Delta_Refresh_Pipeline` your base package?

Comment: Yes. Delta refresh is my base package

Comment: So what available loggers were there?